# How to find intersection of two array-columns

Tags: clickhouse

I got two array(Int32)-columns, is there any way to compare them and get column with the intersection of these two arrays?

I'm thinking about arrayMap function, but it seems to be non-effective approach.

Example data:

```
id     col1      col2     col3
1   [1, 2, 3] [2, 3, 5]  [2, 3]
...........
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/array-functions/#array-functions-arrayintersect

```
SELECT
    [1, 2, 3] AS a,
    [2, 3, 5] AS b,
    arrayIntersect(a, b)

┌─a───────┬─b───────┬─arrayIntersect([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 5])─┐
│ [1,2,3] │ [2,3,5] │ [3,2]                                │
└─────────┴─────────┴──────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks, did not find this in documentation